# Saving a project into an XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

I'm writing a game in java using Netbeans.

I want to be able to save the game to an XML file in the beginning of each round, and to be able to load any saved game in the beginning of the game.

The XML file should eventually include the current state of the game when saved (players, names, sum of money, etc.).

I read over the internet and understood that I need to create a content tree of all the classes of the game using DOM and then Marshall the tree into an XML file, using JAXB.

I have no idea where to start from, how to create the context tree, and so on.

Any help or good tutorial would be helpful (couldn't find anything good).

Comment: I am not sure if it's just like "get everything we have in memory and serialize" and then "get everything back and give me so I can kick it to start". :-) Probably, you'll have to create some object for your game that contains all the data that represent your game "state" and persist it. Some objects simply can't be serialized (such as streams for example)

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, however if you do not know how to read/write XML from java beans using jaxb take a look at this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html. I would start there before trying to make a game.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB enables you to easily convert instances of Java objects to/from XML. With JAXB you will never need to interact directly with DOM.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Game.class);

File file = new File("gameData.xml");

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Game game = (Game) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(game, file);
```

JAXB is configuration by exception meaning you only need to annotate your model where you wan the XML representation to differ from the default.  The following will help you get started:

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted